# MBP + external monitor : alternative to "scaled" display to have smaller apps?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, 4k

I am facing a lot of small annoyance with my external display (4k, 27" benq, T3 connection) like :
it wakes up with the wrong resolution, the mouse feels incredibly slow (it looks like the speed is also "scaled") and some application just struggle to display higher resolution (namely jetbrains products).

So, I moved back to the standard resolution… but everything is too big now. I've reduced the zoom in some apps, but the menus remain huge.

So, are there any solutions (apps or whatnot) to either fix the "scaled" display issues… or to keep the standard resolution, but having slightly smaller apps ?

Thanks a ton…

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what resolutions you're using, but if you use the native 4K resolution *without* scaling, then that will display everything as small as possible.

The whole point of using a 'scaled' display is to keep the clarity of the high-pixel density, while enlarging the screen objects, such as buttons, text, etc.

Comment: My screen has a native 3840 x 2160 but the default resolution is 1980x1050 (x2)

Comment: There should be an option for full size. If not, Holt down Alt/option and click on the "Scaled" radio button, and you should get a larger list of sizes.

Comment: It has, but as I said in the original message any other option than 1050 leads to problems I listed above

Comment: Well, setting the scaling you want is one question; fixing problems with stuttering is another. What exact model of MBP do you have? Does it have discrete GPU? Have you tried a different cable?

Comment: It is a great remark ! My model is the MBP, 13" M1 with 16gig of ram.

So, I first tried to fix the issues and gave up to choose the default resolution of 1080p. I couldn't make the MBP wake up with the right resolution or have a useable mouse speed (even with > 5 settings)

So I figured that having smaller apps might be a simpler solution that trying to fix the other problems